# Messages on MacBook isn't sending or receiving messages, despite being signed in to iCloud

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, icloud, messages

My iPhone is connected to iCloud with the same account. In Messages → Preferences, under "You can be reached for Messages at:" my iPhone's number and my iCloud account are both there and checked.

I have tried restarting Messages, my MacBook, as well as turning iMessage off and on from my phone, and removing the files from `~/Library/Messages`. Nothing so far has worked.

My computer is running El Capitan, and other applications (such as Notes) can sync over iCloud just fine.

Comment: Are you trying to send iMessages (to other iCloud users), or plain SMS/MMS messages?

Comment: Idealing SMS/MMS messages, but I'm pretty sure it would automatically send iMessages to other users with Apple devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to make sure you can send iMessages to other iCloud users. If not, then you’ll want to `Sign Out` of iCloud under **Messages** → **Preferences** → **Accounts**. You may need to reboot your MacBook before signing back in.

If it’s regular text messages (SMS/MMS) that aren’t working, on your iPhone open **Settings** → **Messages** → **Text Message Forwarding** and make sure your MacBook is *enabled*. If it already is, toggle it off, then back on. You will be prompted to enter a verification code sent to your MacBook.

If none of this works, you may need to reboot both devices with everything disabled, then reactivate everything only after booting back up.

Comment: That was it: text Message Forwarding was not turned on! I would have thought that it was automatic, considering the last time I had an iPhone it connected everything right off the bat. Thanks very much.